# How to insert data from a SQL query into a separate SQL query using R in one script?

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, rodbc

I'm trying to write an R script to pull data from two tables in SQL Server. Currently, there are two separate SQL queries: one queries a column of IDs based on year and name; the second uses those IDs found from the first query to then find data we need. Currently, to get the IDs, I just manually change the year and/or the name and then copy and paste the IDs to the second query.

**Is there a way for R to copy and paste the IDs from the first query for me?**

Here's the first SQL query:

```
SELECT Distinct [ID], [col1], [col2], ...
FROM [datatable1]
WHERE Year = XXXX AND Name in ('SomeText')
```

The second query uses the IDs from the first to do the following:

```
SELECT [colA], [colB], ...
FROM [datatable2]
WHERE Year = XXXX and ID in ('ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3',....)
```

Because I am doing this in R using the RODBC package, I was wondering if there is a way for me to do this in one script where it copies and pastes the IDs into the second query for me just by changing the Year and Name from the first query.

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you correctly, you can do what you want in a single query with `exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select col1, col2, ... 
from datatable2 t2
where exists (
    select 1
    from datatable1 t1
    where 
        t1.year = xxxx 
        and t1.name in ('sometext') -- better written as "t1.name = 'sometext'"
        and t1.id = t.id
        ad t1.year = t2.year
)
```